# Angular 2 service subscription not subscribing to my variable

Tags: typescript, angular

My service is returning an array of objects, I’m trying to subscribe the response to my local variable “destinations”. Here is my code:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  destinations = [];

  constructor(public myService: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getDestinations()
        .subscribe(data => {
          destinations = data
       });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  destinations: string[] = [];

  constructor(public myService: MyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getDestinations()
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.destinations = data
       });
  }

}
```

Assuming you're getting an array back. You were missing two this:

first was: destinations: string[] = [];

second: this. in front of destinations, so this.destinations = data;

This should work correctly.

Comment: Just tried this and it worked like a charm. Makes sense that `.this` and array part is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`this.` is missing

```
this.destinations = data
```